# SQL MISTURANDO TUDO

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: SQL MISTURANDO TUDO]
Tenho a seguinte consulta acima conforme a imagem.

Porquê ela está misturando os campos?

```
SELECT 
    celulasreunioes.idCelula, 
    celulas.nome,
    celulas.idRede,
    redes.nome,
    celulas.idRegiao,
    regioes.nome,
    celulas.idArea,
    areas.nome,
    celulas.idSetor,
    setores.nome,                       
    celulasreunioes.data, 
    celulasreunioes.presentes,
    celulasreunioes.visitas,
    celulasreuniOes.criancas,
    celulasreunioes.decisoes,
    celulasreunioes.discipulados,
    celulasreunioes.jejum,
    celulasreunioes.evangelismo,
    celulasreunioes.supervisao,
    celulasreunioes.oferta
FROM celulasreunioes, pastores, redes, regioes, areas, setores, celulas
WHERE
  celulas.idRede = redes.idRede AND
  celulas.idRegiao = regioes.idRegiao AND
  celulas.idArea = areas.idArea AND
  celulas.idSetor = setores.idSetor AND 
  celulas.idPastor = pastores.idPastor AND 
    celulas.idPastor = 2 AND 
    data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
/*GROUP BY celulas.idCelula*/
ORDER BY celulas.idSetor
```

Por exemplo:

A **Célula** de **17** é a **Célula 1**
A **Célula** de **18** é a **Célula 2**

Mas a `query` diz que as Células **17 e 18** são as mesmo tempo a **1 e a 2**

Caso eu descomente a linha

```
/*GROUP BY celulas.idCelula*/
```

Que é o **objetivo**, o **retorno** fica ainda pior pois *omite* o **resultado** para a **Célula 18** conforme figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O retorno esperado (com as demais clausulas da **query**) )é como na figura abaixo que tem apenas a print da tabela de reuniões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo a ajudo do Rafael Dias, e como `**NÃO**` há como postar uma nova resposta para ajudar no fórum pois colocaram a pergunta como pendente, vou colocar aqui mesmo como ficou a `query` final,mas já **compilada**

```
SELECT 
     celulasreunioes.idCelula, 
     celulas.nome as nomeCelula,
     pastores.idPastor,
     membros.nome as nomePastor,
     celulas.idRede,
     redes.nome as nomeRede,
     celulas.idRegiao,
     regioes.nome as nomeRegiao,
     celulas.idArea,
     areas.nome as nomeArea,
     celulas.idSetor,
     setores.nome as nomeSetor,                      
     celulasreunioes.data, 
     celulasreunioes.presentes,
     celulasreunioes.visitas,
     celulasreuniOes.criancas,
     celulasreunioes.decisoes,
     celulasreunioes.discipulados,
     celulasreunioes.jejum,
     celulasreunioes.evangelismo,
     celulasreunioes.supervisao,
     celulasreunioes.oferta
FROM
     celulasreunioes, 
     pastores, 
     redes, 
     regioes, 
     areas, 
     setores, 
     celulas, 
     membros
WHERE
     celulas.idRede = redes.idRede AND
     celulas.idRegiao = regioes.idRegiao AND
     celulas.idArea = areas.idArea AND
     celulas.idSetor = setores.idSetor AND 
     celulas.idCelula = celulasreunioes.idCelula AND 
     celulas.idPastor = pastores.idPastor AND 
     pastores.idPastor = membros.idMembro AND 
     data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW() 
ORDER BY 
    celulas.nome, 
    membros.nome,
    redes.nome, 
    regioes.nome, 
    areas.nome, 
    setores.nome
```

Comment: E quais são os dados presentes na tabela? Qual seria o resultado esperado?

Comment: adicionado à pergunta!

Comment: adiciona tambem um select da celulas igual a 17 e 18. So para ter certeza que sua tabela nao tem dado duplicado.

Comment: não posso pois vão existir mais de 300 células, nesse momento de desenvolvimento só cadastrei essas 2.. Ou não entendi tua orientação.

Comment: select * form celulasreunioes where idCelula = 17

Comment: Então está afirmando que existem apenas **dois registros** na tabela? Consegue criar um [mcve] utilizando o https://www.db-fiddle.com/?

Comment: A query está executando perfeitamente. Se quer um resultado diferente do esperado, queira [edit] a questão e colocar uma demonstração do resultado esperado e uma explicação de porque acha que deveria ser diferente do apresentado. Da forma como está, não dá para saber onde é que está o erro de lógica (a resposta dada pode ser uma solução, mas só sabendo ao certo qual é a intenção original)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seus JOINS não estão funcionando corretamente e, como está, há um CROSS JOIN entre `celulas` e `celulasreunioes` - ou seja, todos os valores de `celulasreunioes` aparecerão repetidos.

Repare que na cláusula WHERE a tabela `celulasreunioes` não aparece. Ela tem que ser vinculada às outras.

```
FROM celulasreunioes, pastores, redes, regioes, areas, setores, celulas
WHERE
  celulas.idRede = redes.idRede AND
  celulas.idRegiao = regioes.idRegiao AND
  celulas.idArea = areas.idArea AND
  celulas.idSetor = setores.idSetor AND 
  celulas.idPastor = pastores.idPastor AND 
    celulas.idPastor = 2 AND 
    data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Uma vantagem de utilizar a sintaxe de INNER JOINs do padrão ANSI é que simplifica pegar esses detalhes. Por exemplo, transformando o WHERE acima em JOINs o problema fica aparente:

```
FROM celulas
  INNER JOIN pastores ON celulas.idPastor = pastores.idPastor
  INNER JOIN redes ON celulas.idRede = redes.idRede
  INNER JOIN regioes ON celulas.idRegiao = regioes.idRegiao
  INNER JOIN areas ON celulas.idArea = areas.idArea
  INNER JOIN setores ON celulas.idSetor = setores.idSetor
  --FALTOU o celulasreunioes
WHERE
    celulas.idPastor = 2 AND 
    data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: obrigado, query final, no fim da pergunta